# Does r2dbc repository support dynamic SQL conjecture?

Tags: sql, dynamic, spring-data, repository, r2dbc

I was migrating traditional JPA based project to reactive Project, which was based on r2dbc.

There have many dynamics SQL conjecture in our project before, like if user pass parameter exchange value as CME，we will add "**and exchange='CME'**" at the end of SQL and run it by JDBCTemplate:

```
    List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = QUERY_BrokerIDs_Old;

    sql += " and exchange = ?";

    parameters.add(exchange);

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filter)) {
      sql += " and memberID like ?";
      parameters.add("%" + filter.trim().toUpperCase() + "%");
    }

    sql += " order by id";

    if (page > 0 && pageSize > 0) {
      int offset = (page - 1) * pageSize;
      String pageClause = PAGE_CLAUSE;
      sql += pageClause;
      parameters.add(offset);
      parameters.add(pageSize);
    }

    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, parameters.toArray(), String.class);
```

I found r2dbc repository provide multiple convient methods, like  findAll, getXxxByXxx,I really like it. And we also can declare the SQL in @Query like:

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE lastname = :lastname")
  Flux<Person> findByLastname(String lastname);
```

But does it support dynamic parameter as query conditions in its repository class? Or I can do some customize on it to implement it?
Otherwise I only can implement it by SQL conjecture and run it by template， like the old way before…

Comment: Is using another third party library an option? jOOQ 3.15 supports R2DBC and offers a ton of dynamic SQL capabilities: https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/15/reactive-sql-with-jooq-3-15-and-r2dbc